# Div getting out of the screen

Tags: html, css, screen

Idunno how to explain it well, but here is the code:

CSS:

```
.top-container 
{
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    float: left;
    width: 1920px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="top-container">
            <h1>
                Text
            </h1>
            <h4>
                some more text :)</b>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And results didn't looked as expected:

[What I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgyBj.png)

[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPlrS.png)

Comment: its because you make the rookie mistake of giving it a fixed with instead of width `100%` or `100vw` or `auto`. Then your body uses a margin and padding which needs to be resetted to 0.

Answer (score 2):

`body` margin is 8px as a default, and you need to set it to 0.

Also, update the `top-container` width to 100%.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  float: left;
  width: 100%; // fix this from 1920px to 100%
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-container">
    <h1>
      Text
    </h1>
    <h4>
      some more text :)</b>
    </h4>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```